# Python regex with negative matching

Tags: python, regex

I have a following text file as *sample.txt*:

```
xe-4/3/1.1596
xe-4/3/1.1528
ae2.670
xe-4/3/1.1503
ae2
xe-4/3/1.1478
xe-4/3/1.1475
xe-4/3/1.1469
xe-4/3/1
xe-4/3/1.3465
xe-4/0/0.670
xe-4/0/0
xe-4/3/1.1446
xe-4/0/0.544
xe-4/3/1.1437
gr-5/0/0
gr-5/0/0.10
lo0.16384
lo0.16385
em1
em1.0
cbp0
demux0
irb
pip0
pp0
ae0
```

This is the list of interfaces of a router.
I need to print out the lines (interfaces) which contain: *xe,ae,gr* but the ones which does not containg dot, e.g *xe-4/3/1*, *gr-5/0/0*, *ae2* etc.

Trying the following code but it does not work:

```
import re

file = open('sample.txt','r')
string = file.read()

for f in string:
    matchObj = re.findall("(xe|ae|gr)[^.]*$", f)
    if matchObj:
        print f
```

Checked my regex **(xe|ae|gr)[^.]*$** at http://regexr.com/ and it matches the lines I want. Could you tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: It doesn't work _how_?

Comment: @ForceBru it is obvious that the "does not work" means: neither produces any output, nor any error.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, _this does not work_ may mean: giving errors, giving strange output, giving errors with strange output, giving nothing, shutting down while it shouldn't, etc

Comment: No, it is obvious to me, and on this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for f in string:` will iterate over characters in file; you want to iterate over lines. I suggest the following code instead:

```
# use the with statement to open the file
with open('sample.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        # use re.search to see if there is match on the line;
         # but we do not care about the actual matching strings
        if re.search("(xe|ae|gr)[^.]*$", line):
            print line
```

Comment: Antti, thanks for your answer. I get the point now. If you dont mind I would like to extend my question a little bit. Please see the edited question. I thought I could handle but it seems that I am stuck.

Comment: @jeronimo777, you could make a new post for your extended question. It's good for us since it cleanly separates individual questions into individual posts, and it's good for you because you'll get more attention on the new questions list.